# Keep website picture size when zooming out

Tags: html, css

I find it quite annoying that pictures resize/get zommed in-out when zooming in/out on a website (Ctrl+Mouse-scroll). I have looked at Call Of Duty (http://bit.ly/1FnXMNA) and Heroes Of The Storm's (http://bit.ly/1BQ4Jdr) website, they seem to have some kind of solution to this, but I simply haven't found any searching.

I am wanting to do this;

Normal size/zoom website [image: Normal size/zoom website]
After zooming out [image]

The picture/gif(/maybe video..?) does not get resized, how do I do this?

Comment: Just use background-size: cover; and don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file, where you have have background image, add `no-repeat center center fixed` to the end.

So it will look something like:

```
html {
    background: url(images/someImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```